# Python String Slicing Tutorial

Tags: python, string, slice

I am currently studying Python at school. I don't understand what the book is trying to explain and my instructor isn't very helpful. The book gives the following example:

```
usr_text = input('Enter a string: ')
print()

first_half = usr_text[:len(usr_text)//2]
last_half = usr_text[len(usr_text)//2:]

print('The first half of the string is "{}"'.format(first_half))
print('The second half of the string is "{}"'.format(last_half))
```

I don't understand what

```
[:len(usr_text)//2]
```

&

```
[len(usr_text)//2:]
```

does. Would anyone mind explaining what's happening there and why it's used? Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Comment: `//` is an integer division (as opposed to floating-point `/`), so you are slicing to half of the string by measuring its length and dividing that by 2

Comment: `foo[:x]` is equivalent to `foo[0:x]` which means "the elements from `0` up to but not including `x`". Similarly `foo[x:]` means "the elements from `x` to the end of the sequence"

Comment: Thank you all! The link to the similar question helped a lot.